# Strip path pandas in datafraeme

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I have this dataframe in pandas

```
     path                                               variable             
0   /home/opt/chat                                          A                      
1   /home/test                                              B                   
2   /home/opt/projects                                      C
3   /home/opt/projects/ex/remove/results                    D
```

How do I strip the column path to return this output in my dataframe?

```
     path                                               variable             
0    chat                                                 A                      
1    test                                                 B                     
2    projects                                             C
3    results                                              D
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) wth select last value by indexing:

```
df['path'] = df['path'].astype(str).str.split('/').str[-1]
print (df)
       path variable
0      chat        A
1      test        B
2  projects        C
3   results        D
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @SimonGIS - Can you try `df['path'] = df['path'].astype(str).str.split('/').str[-1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1`, to limit to one split:

```
df['path'] = df['path'].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1]
```

or, maybe better, [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a short regex `([^/]+$)` (any series of non-`/` characters `[^/]+`, just before the end of line `$`):

```
df['path'] = df['path'].str.extract(r'([^/]+$)', expand=False)
```

output:

```
       path variable
0      chat        A
1      test        B
2  projects        C
3   results        D
```